# How to settle error with: 'RawImage' does not contain a definition for 'SetActive' (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have one task which is I want to open and close my panel with KeyCode. I found out this code but after I try this code I keep getting this error:

'RawImage' does not contain a definition for 'SetActive' and no accessible extension method 'SetActive' accepting a first argument of type 'RawImage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here I attached the code. I don't know why. Can someone explain and teach me?

```
public class GameObject : MonoBehaviour {
public RawImage GO;
void Awake()
{
    GO.SetActive(false);
}
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.V))
    {
        GO.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        GO.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I strongly recommend to not call your component `GameObject` .. that's a built-in type of Unity .. how confusing will that be!

Comment: Hi @derHugo Thankyou for you advise! I will improve more after this

Answer (score 1):

GameObject has definition of SetActive not RawImage. So in order to make that gameObject False you have to access GameObject Of RawImage like this and it will work

```
GO.gameObject.SetActive(false);
GO.gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

Comment: Hi @Jaimin thankyou for your reply! I've try the way you post . and It's works! there is no errors in script anymore. But I have another problem here. I can't apply the script to GameObject. It's popup this thing "Can't add script component because the script class cannot be found? Make sure that there are no compile errors and that file name and class name match" . I am pretty sure my file and class name are same. Do you know why?

Comment: By the way is it related to Unity version? Because I use Unity2019.4.31f1

Comment: Hi @Jaimin the problem before solved! but there is another problem :( the error is: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Try2.Awake () . I didn't found how to solved it. Can you help me?